# Access database deployed in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have created created a kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 2 nodes  in our data centre and deployed a postgres database in it.  I would like to access database with with Pgadmin

Comment: Use a kubernetes service to expose this deployment to the world, and use the service url (whether its a load balancer or a node port) to access this deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose the Postgres instance by setting up a node port service. Allow only specific IP addresses to access that service, this prevent unauthorized access.